# ZIJANG-8330 Thermal Receipt Printer is writing blank page using Google Cloud print (GCP) in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-print

I'm trying to send printing job to my printer using Google Cloud print API in Python. My printer is ZIJANG-8330 Thermal Receipt Printer. It's size 80 * 210 mm. When I send print job it's writing blank page. This is my ticket json. How can I solve it?

```
ticketnew = { "version":"1.0", "print":{ "vendor_ticket_item":[], 
"page_orientation": { "type":"PORTRAIT", }, "color":
{"type":"STANDARD_MONOCHROME" }, "margins":{ "top_microns":0, 
"right_microns":0, "bottom_microns":0, "left_microns":0 }, 
"fit_to_page":{ "type":1 }, "copies":{ "copies":1 }, "media_size": { 
"width_microns":80000, "height_microns": 210000, 
"is_continuous_feed":False}, } }
```

Comment: `$`??? Is that Python? How do you actually send the job. What is the payload?

Comment: Payload is okey. Problem is about my ticket.